# Windows 7: Automated folder action on copy

Tags: video, windows-7, encoding, automation

I'm running Windows 7 pro. I have a folder called "Media" in the root of my C:\ What I want to do is that when I copy some form of video media, ex .mov file to that folder, that it would detect the copy, once completed, fire handbrake or FFMPEG via the command line and encode, pushing to another directory under "Media", such as encoded, totally automated so that I don't even need to think about encoding video.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? I can link some relevant libraries and things like that, but not write it for you.

Comment: ... What's an easy plugin and play solution?

Comment: Other then using a language is there any Prebuilt solution to meet my needs?

Comment: What libraries are you thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but you can merge this [blog post](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) with `os.system()` to run Handbrake and get a working system.

Comment on my answer or make a new question if you run into trouble implementing it, as that I can at least try to answer concretely.